# Why could weak-strong dance break retain cycle?

Tags: ios, objective-c

This is my code:

```
NSLog(@"%p",self);

__weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
NSLog(@"%p", weakSelf);

[self setBlk:^{
    __strong typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;
    NSLog(@"%p", strongSelf);

    strongSelf.str = @"foo";
}];

self.blk();
```

`blk` and `str` is property.

and I got the log like this:

```
2018-04-03 14:51:57.151946+0800 Block[20267:148833] 0x7fafa1506d90
2018-04-03 14:51:57.152177+0800 Block[20267:148833] 0x7fafa1506d90
2018-04-03 14:51:57.152359+0800 Block[20267:148833] 0x7fafa1506d90
```

The conclusion is `self`、`weakSelf` and `strongSelf` point to the same object, the different of them is just strong or weak. In my opinion, `self` and `strongSelf` is identical. so I think the memory of this code like this:

[image]

My confusion is when block is executed, block will strong reference self, but if self is not dealloced in the same time, self also strong reference block. Will it cause retain cycle?

Comment: at the first glance it seems you mix the _pointer_ with _reference_ here; as long as the _pointer_ of the instance is identical the _references_ are completely different as their scopes as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In my opinion,  it won't cause retain cycle. I think you misunderstand some points.

- Block doesn't keep strong reference of `self`, it keeps a weak reference.
- `self` and `strongSelf` isn't identical.
- **`strongSelf` is strong reference of `weakSelf` not `self`** so it won't cause retain cycle.
- If `self` is not deallocated when block executed, `strongSelf` will be a strong reference of `self`. But `strongSelf` is a local variable ,it only makes self can't be deallocated until block executed completely.

Comment: I suddenly understand the confusion about retain cycle, when block is executed, it will not reference self. I agree your first opinion, but the second and third I don't agree. Because, `weakSelf` and `strongSelf` have the same value. `weakSelf` and `strongSelf` point to the same object, you mean `strongSelf` point to `weakSelf`?

Comment: I mean when you write `__strong typeof(weakSelf) strongSelf = weakSelf;`, `strongSelf` points to object which is pointed by `weakSelf`. If `weakSelf` point to `self`, `strongSelf ` will be strong reference of `self` .But if `self` is deallocated, at this time `weakSelf` point to `nil` so `strongSelf` will point to `nil` too

Comment: I assume _self is not dealloced when block executed_.

Now, I think the key of this question is block will not strong reference self when it executed, because block strong reference self only when it capture self.

Thank you!

Comment: *If self is not deallocated when block executed, `strongSelf` will be a strong reference of `self`*. But `strongSelf` is a local variable ,it only makes `self` can't be deallocated until block executed completely. That's the key.

Comment: Yes, block will not strong reference self, I mix it. Thanks~